# Listen to multiple nodes in firestore...?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

in my example I have a collection "companies" with 50 different companies each of them have a collection "addedShifts" - in my node.js I would like to set up a listener that listenes to "addedShifts"  of each of thoese companies is it possible or I have to come up ith a walkaround for that?

would like to have something like this :

```
firestore.document("companies/{*}/addedShifts").onWrite()=>
```

where {*} would be a 'wildcard' for company ID

Comment: I wrote an answer for Node.js below, but only now see that you tagged with Cloud Functions. Are you looking to do this in a regular Node.js client, or in Cloud Functions? Because the answer might be quite different between the two.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sorry for that ,for cloud-functions (will delet node.js tag) -is the answer you refer still relative to my case ..?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The second example in this [documentation section](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#wildcards-parameters) seems to indicate it is possible:

> ```
> // Listen for changes in all documents and all subcollections
> exports.useMultipleWildcards = functions.firestore
>     .document('users/{userId}/{messageCollectionId}/{messageId}')
>     .onWrite((event) => {
>         // If we set `/users/marie/incoming_messages/134` to {body: "Hello"} then
>         // event.params.userId == "malcolm";
>         // event.params.messageCollectionId == "incoming_messages";
>         // event.params.messageId == "134";
>         // ... and ...
>         // event.data.data() == {body: "Hello"}
>     });
> ```

Are you having problems getting it to work?

Comment: great, missed that section in documentation -will look into it , ty:) (y)